# Cannot handover attrs.value to Directive's templateUrl function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using Angular 1.6 I am defining an directive like so:

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive('lyEntity', lyEntity);

function lyEntity() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            model: '=',
            type: '@'
        },
        controller: 'lyEntityController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true,
        templateUrl: function (elem, attrs) {
            return 'components/_templates/' + attrs.type + '.html'
        }
    };
}
```

But using it in another template like so:

```
<ly-entity model="vm.entity" type="{{vm.type}}"></ly-entity>
```

will result in templateURL `components/_templates/{{vm.type}}.html`

How can I hand over the value of `vm.type` to be used in my `templateUrl` function?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it can't be done the way you're trying to do it because `templateUrl` function is called before the attributes are interpolated. One way to achieve this would be using `ng-include`.

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        type: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        $scope.templateUrl = 'components/_templates/' + attrs.type + '.html';
    },
    template: '<ng-include src="templateUrl"/>'
};
```

So, construct the template url in *controller*, have `ng-include` as the template and point the *src* to the constructed template url.

Here's a good article on how to have dynamic templates: https://medium.com/angularjs-meetup-south-london/angular-directives-using-a-dynamic-template-c3fb16d03c6d#.mizywdk6s

Comment: I have to use `$attrs` in controller instead of `attrs`, right? I solved it a bit different and provide an answer - wasn't able to get it running using your example but it guided me into the right direction, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Chantu, I found a solution which is working for me:

Directive:

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive('lyEntity', lyEntity);

function lyEntity() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            model: '=',
            type: '='
        },
        controller: 'lyEntityController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true,
        template: '<ng-include src="templateUrl"/>'
    };
}
```

Controller:

```
$scope.templateUrl = 'components/_templates/' + vm.type + '.html';
```

and call it:

```
<ly-entity model="vm.entity" type="vm.type"></ly-entity>
```